# How to change the restricted three body problem to dimensionless coordinates?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, dimensional-analysis

I'm reading Theory of Orbit: The Restricted Problem of Three Bodies Victory Szebehely, and I'm having a problem to change the problem to dimensionless coordinates.

The original system is 
    \begin{split}
\frac{d^2X}{dt^{*2}}&=-\frac{m_1}{R_1^3}(X-b\cos{\omega t^*})-\frac{m_2}{R_2^3}(X+a\cos{\omega t^*})\\
\frac{d^2Y}{dt^{*2}}&=-\frac{m_1}{R_1^3}(Y-b\sin{\omega t^*})-\frac{m_2}{R_2^3}(Y+a\sin{\omega t^*}),\\   
\end{split}

where $R_1=\sqrt{(X-b\cos{\omega t^*})^2+(Y-b\sin{\omega t^*})^2}$ and $R_2=\sqrt{(X+a\cos{\omega t^*})^2+(Y+a\sin{\omega t^*})^2}$

The change of variables that Victory Szebehely makes is:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    \xi = \frac{X}{R},\eta=\frac{Y}{R},t=\omega t^*,\mu_1=\frac{a}{R}=\frac{m_1}{m_1+m_2},\mu_2&=\frac{b}{R}=\frac{m_2}{m_1+m_2},\rho_1=\frac{R_1}{R},\rho_2=\frac{R_2}{R},
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
where $R$ is a constant, the distance between the primaries, that  accordind to kepler third law satisfies the following relation: $\omega^2=\frac{m_1+m_2}{R^3}.$
I'm suppose to arrive to this:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
     \frac{d^2\xi}{dt^{2}}&=-\frac{\mu_1}{\rho_1^3}(\xi-\mu_2\cos{t})-\frac{\mu_2}{\rho_2^3}(\xi+\mu_1\cos{t})\\
     \frac{d^2\eta}{dt^{2}}&=-\frac{\mu_1}{\rho_1^3}(\eta-\mu_2\sin{t})-\frac{\mu_2}{\rho_2^3}(\eta+\mu_1\sin{t}).\\  
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

The main problem I'm having is that I don't know how to obtain the second derivative with respect to $t$.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your original system involves $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$, but your change of variables involves $R$ as well.  What is $R$?

Comment: You *do* know that  $d^2/dt^2$ has the exact dimensions of $1/t^2$, don't you?

Comment: ...but at some point, in front of each of the 4 parentheses on the r.h.s.  he appears to also use something like $m_i/(m_1+m_2)=\mu_i$, which you gave us no warning about. Are you sure there are no two types of *μ* variable?

Comment: Thanks for your hint, and sorry for skipping that part. The hint was my really my doubt, I will try to do it again knowing that $\frac{d^2}{dt^{*2}}=\frac{1}{\omega^2}\frac{d^2}{dt^2}$